# ASP.NET Core Web API : ContentResult application/json removing duplicate properties in json string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my Web API, I am returning a string containing json data using `ContentResult` like this:

```
return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

But strangely, it is removing duplicate properties in my json. So if I try to return this string as `ContentResult`

```
{
    "id": 1840,
    "action_checklist_id": 145,
    "id": 6891,
    "categories_id": 1
}
```

I get this

```
{
    "id": 6891,
    "action_checklist_id": 145,
    "categories_id": 1
}
```

You can see that it removed one of the `id` properties because it was duplicate, not only that it put the value of last most `id` property to the very first one and removed all the rest `id` properties.

I checked this behavior with even more duplicated `id` properties.

Is there any way to control this automatic behavior of `ContentResult`?

Comment: This seems to be related to the JSON serializer itself and is also not recommended [(JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4)

Comment: you want to change your models (frontend/backend) to use a List of IDs if you want to send multiple.

Answer (score 0):

c# doesn't allow duplicated property object so cannot parse. You could convert the json string to KeyValuePair list which allow depulicated keys. And return the KeyValuepair list as "application/json"

```
[HttpGet("test")]

public IActionResult test()
{
    var jsonString = "{\r\n    \"id\": 1840,\r\n    \"action_checklist_id\": 145,\r\n    \"id\": 6891,\r\n    \"categories_id\": 1\r\n}";

    char[] separators = new char[] { ' ', '{', '}', '\r','\n', '\\','\"' };
    string[] temp = jsonString.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var trimedString = String.Join("", temp);
    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (var pair in trimedString.Split(","))
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pair.Split(":")[0], pair.Split(":")[1]));
    }
         
    return Ok(list);
}
```

Test reuslt
[image]